# Spring transaction rollback on exception continues to execute code after throw

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have a service to schedule a meeting and send a confirmation e-mail and I noticed that if I click the submit button many times, multiple emails will be sent.

The service is this:

```
@Service
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
public class MeetingService {
    public void scheduleAndInvite(int meetingId) {
        try {
            Meeting meeting = meetingDao.loadById(meetingId);

            // Validations.
            if (meeting.getMeetingStatus() != MeetingStatus.Draft) {
                throw new FmcUserException("not draft");
            }

            // Persist entity
            meeting.setMeetingStatus(MeetingStatus.Scheduled);

            meetingDao.persistMyEntity(meeting);

            // This eventually calls JavaMailSender. Uses the Meeting hibernate entity
            sendInvitations(meeting);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            throw new FmcSystemException(ex); // This class extends RuntimeException.
        }
    }
```

When clicking multiple times on Submit (in the browser) I was expecting the first test (Status != draft) to be sufficient in evaluating that this meeting is already scheduled. In that case the exception is thrown, is caught by the catch block thus skipping the sendInvitations() call.

It correctly generates a ton of exceptions in the log:

```
12:45:01,117 ERROR [my.framework.mvc.BaseController] (default task-55) could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement: org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:232)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:755)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$3.convert(MySQLDialect.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

I cannot possibly understand how on earth this sends Multiple emails. I have read here that spring continues execution until the end of the method but why?! After an exception is thrown why should execution continue beyond the throw() statement?

I know that this issue can be solved by wrapping the sendEmail call in:

```
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterCommit() {
            sendInvitations(meeting);
        }
    });
```

But then again. why ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Spring definitely does not carry on execution after the exception. The reason multiple emails are sent is because there is a race condition. if you press submit multiple times the same request is executed in parallel, thus `meetingDao.loadById` can be executed many times before you get to the point in your code where the update is done.

Comment: I see. Is it because the commit is only performed at the end of the transaction? If so is there a way to force the commit imeddiately after the update? Or is it a better approach to the use TransactionSynchronizationManager ?

Comment: You can force the commit, but you will still have a race condition, since multiple entrants can get to the read section before the transaction is committed. A "simple" fix is to disable the submit button once the request is submitted. This does not stop anyone from calling the endpoint directly though. With a system problem like this I would normally suggest idem-potency of your requests; however, it may be complete overkill for what you are doing.

Comment: Understood. I will for now use the TransactionSynchronizationManager to execute non-transactional methods after commit. If you'd like to upgrade your comments to a full answer (to help others) I would accept it.

Comment: @Leon please upgrade your comment to answer so that I can accept it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is not executing code after an exception is thrown. There is no way that's even possible, this is simply how java works.

It seems to me that this is because by pushing submit multiple times, you are sending a request to your server multiple times which get executed in parallel. at some point the different threads are going to get in each other's way.

If you want to properly solve this, you will need to either synchronize this code, or take a database lock preventing other transactions from going through. (Using a SELECT .... FOR UPDATE or some other means)